# background image distorted Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, desktop-background

[image]I am using HP-laptop-15q-by0xx AMD® A9-9420 radeon r5, 5 compute cores 2c+3g × 2  with AMD Stoney graphics.Suddenly one of the Desktop background image distorted. I am attaching the image of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version of that wallpaper looks equally distorted ;-) Do not worry: that is not your computer failing. That background is designed like that.